Jmeter: unable to extract value from nested array
I am trying to automate load testing on Jmeter in order to be able to schedule them and let them run at specific times. I have no powers over the queues nor our rabbit scenery in general, I can only send and retrieve.
I can schedule the sending of messages to our own queue on rabbitmq just fine. However, then I need to be able to check if they all made it safely there. So, I extracted all the messageId values from the sent messages, and need to see if the queues contains them.
I managed to get the last (number I need) of messages from the queue as a whole text, it looks like this:
[{
        "payload_bytes": 702,
        "payload": "{\"receiver\":\"randomnumbers\",\"expiration_ts\":\"2024-07-03T15:13:45.812+02:00\",\"la_id\":\"miao\",\"service_name\":\"miao2\",\"la_message_code\":\"05c77901-fb4b-4b9a-8dfc-be2af1d0e2f0\",\"wa_account\":\"393511491882\",\"metadata\":{\"mkt\/servizio\":\"link:it\",\"ubm\/acceptingDate\":\"2024-07-02T15:13:45.772+02:00\",\"ubm\/ubmMessageSid\":\"05c77901-fb4b-4b9a-8dfc-be2af1d0e2f0\",\"miao5\":\"miao3\",\"la\/category\":\"Service\",\"la\/subCli\":\"miao6\",\"mkt\/ambiente\":\"Test\",\"mkt\/groupServiceSid\":\"miao7\",\"afc\/ambiente\":\"Test\",\"mkt\/service_name\":\"miao2\"},\"template_foreign_id\":\"miao4\",\"template_params\":[\"1\",\"text2\",\"text3\",\"text4\",\"text5\",\"text6\",\"text7\",\"text8\",\"text9\",\"text10\"]}",
        "payload_encoding": "string",
        "exchange": "",
        "routing_key": "miaoqueue",
        "message_count": 522,
        "redelivered": true,
        "properties": {
            "headers": {
                "x-delay": 0
            },
            "content_type": "application\/octet-stream",
            "priority": 0,
            "delivery_mode": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "payload_bytes": 702,
        "payload": "{\"receiver\":\"randomnumbers\",\"expiration_ts\":\"2024-07-03T15:13:45.837+02:00\",\"la_id\":\"miao\",\"service_name\":\"miao2\",\"la_message_code\":\"bdc77f92-66d8-45c7-8114-7cde780421d6\",\"wa_account\":\"393511491882\",\"metadata\":{\"mkt\/servizio\":\"miao4\",\"ubm\/acceptingDate\":\"2024-07-02T15:13:45.767+02:00\",\"ubm\/ubmMessageSid\":\"bdc77f92-66d8-45c7-8114-7cde780421d6\",\"miao5\":\"miao3\",\"la\/category\":\"Service\",\"la\/subCli\":\"miao6\",\"mkt\/ambiente\":\"Test\",\"mkt\/groupServiceSid\":\"miao7\",\"afc\/ambiente\":\"Test\",\"mkt\/service_name\":\"miao2\"},\"template_foreign_id\":\"miao4\",\"template_params\":[\"1\",\"text2\",\"text3\",\"text4\",\"text5\",\"text6\",\"text7\",\"text8\",\"text9\",\"text10\"]}",
        "payload_encoding": "string",
        "exchange": "",
        "routing_key": "miaoqueue",
        "message_count": 521,
        "redelivered": true,
        "properties": {
            "headers": {
                "x-delay": 0
            },
            "content_type": "application\/octet-stream",
            "priority": 0,
            "delivery_mode": 2
        }
    }]

However, it runs a lot of times. I also managed to slice it into single payload items via a json extractor:
$..payload

Then I get all of them listed out and numbered using a JSR223:

int payloadCount=vars.get("payload_matchNr").toInteger()
def lstPayload =[]

for(i in 1..payloadCount){
    lstPayload.add(vars.get("payload_" + i))
}
vars.putObject("payload", lstPayload)

My issue is that I can't get all the "la_message_code" entries out of this thing (that's how the messageId value is called here).
Once I get them all out, I want to be able to do something like:
for each la_message_code, try to see if it contains any of the messageId that I extracted previously.

something like this would capture the code to group 1

Groovy has built-in JSON support hence you can do everything in one shot:
def payloads = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).payload

payloads.eachWithIndex { payload, index ->
    vars.put('la_message_code_' + (index + 1), (new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(payload).la_message_code))
}

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?

Oh you absolute national treasure!

Just a quick edit:
I see the correct results all listed neatly in the response body, and if i apply my final assert to the whole text response it will find the message id; however, if i only apply it to the new la_message_code_ variable, it says:
Assertion error:false
Assertion failure:true
Assertion failure message:Response was null

variables look like la_message_code_1=05c77901-fb4b-4b9a-8dfc-be2af1d0e2f0 and la_message_code_2=bdc77f92-66d8-45c7-8114-7cde780421d6. You can see which JMeter Variables are defined with their respective values using Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination

Ah yes thank you, i did that to be sure it actually grabbed the correct part of the whole payload, and it did thanks to you! But then i wanted to put an assert to check automatically the presence of the messageid in the list of all the la_message_code. Problem is, how can i tell it to check every item in the la_message_code list if the variable name contains a different number for every entry?

I DID IT! I made a concat string with groovy and applied the Assert to it! Yay!
